# Push notification issue on fcm key using davibennun/laravel-push-notification library

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification

I am working on push notifications. For sending push notifications on devices from my laravel code/project I configured this liberary
[davibennun/laravel-push-notification](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification)

I am using fcm key generation for android devices so when I send token to fcm key and set service from GCM to FCM in configuration file then I always receive following error

```
Class 'Sly\NotificationPusher\Adapter\Fcm' not found
```

But I revert it to gcm service type then I did not receive any notification and in reponse I received always empty array

```
Array
(
)
```

Kindly help out to trace and fix this issue or suggest any other usefull library for laravel compatible library that send push notification to FCM,GCM and APNS.

Thanks